# How can I combine calls to Dir#[] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How could I refactor this code to use only one Dir[ ] call?

```
Dir[ File.join('.', 'directory_a'), '*' ] + Dir[ File.join('.', 'directory_b'), '*' ]
=> [ contents of directory_a and directory_b ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dir['./{directory_a,directory_b}/*']
```